# Is there an alternative to onEdit(e)?

Tags: google-apps-script

Disclaimer: I'm a relative newb.

I'm grabbing a user's calendar events and displaying them on a Google Sheet. One column gets partially filled in based on code. Users can then add their own values. Unfortunately, when they run my code again all their user-entered values will, of course, be lost.

Last night I decided to "save" the user-entered values on a new sheet by associating them with the event IDs. I tried to implement this using onEdit(e) but the trigger isn't working. (I am guessing because I'm grabbing the user's calendar?)

Is there an alternative to onEdit(e)? (It would be pretty easy to keep track of which values were generated by code -- and I could tell the added ones that way -- but to save their values users would have to click an extra button, which doesn't feel very user friendly...)

Comment: The function name `onEdit()` is a reserved function name.  When the Sheet is edited, Apps Script looks for a function named `onEdit()`  This avoids the need to do any set-up to associate a function name with the Edit event.  But `onEdit()` is a simple trigger that runs under restrictions.  You can "install" an On Edit trigger using a different function name, which will run without the same restrictions, but the user needs to authorize any permissions that the script needs.  Click the Help menu in the code editor, and choose "documentation."  Search installed triggers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm a bit confused about the restrictions. If my bound script accesses the user's calendar, but NOT any of the code in my onEdit() function, should it still work?

I added some very basic code to change the text in a cell if the adjacent cell is edited. It works if I start a new sheet. But when I copy that exact code to my calendar analyzer (to change the adjacent cell), nothing happens.

Comment: I try not to think in terms of what "should" or "shouldn't" work.  There are requirements that need to be met, and if they are met, then the code will run correctly.  If a function fails, it should show up as failed in the Apps Script dashboard for your Executions.  [https://script.google.com/home/executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions)  From the "View" menu, do you have an "Execution transcript" menu item?  If so, run the code, then open the Execution transcript log and scroll to the bottom.  Is there an error message with a line number that failed?

Comment: If your simple triggered onEdit() function performs any operation that requires user permissions then it will fail.  Your only alternative is to utilize an installable onEdit trigger and please do not name it onEdit.  When you first setup installable triggers it's really handy to change notificiations to immediate so that google will send you immediate notifications for failures via email.

Comment: Hello, Coooper. When you say " When you first setup installable triggers..." What do you mean by that? What setup is involved? (Other than just adding an onEdit() function?)

Comment: One quick followup question. To test that my trigger is working I am simply changing a cell to the word "Works!" But once I edit a cell and press ENTER it takes about 3 seconds before that word appears. Is this normal? Why is it so slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creating an onEdit trigger programatically**

The alternative to [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) is [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).  Simple triggers cannot perform events that require permission.  Installable triggers can if the user using it provides authorization.

Since I'm always working on other peoples code I have a couple of helper functions that make creating the installable onEdit trigger easier to create.

This is what you will see in my code sometimes.  It allows me to create the onEdit functions quickly while at the same time performing all of the house keeping chores that I want it to perform.

```
function createOnEditTrigger() {
  createOnEditTriggerForSpreadsheet('MyFunctionName');
}
```

But behind the scenes there's another helper function that takes that funcname and checks to make sure that there isn't already a trigger assigned to that function name.  If there is then it won't create another one.

```
function createOnEditTriggerForSpreadsheet(funcname) {
  var ssid=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  if(!isTrigger(funcname)) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcname).forSpreadsheet(ssid).onEdit().create();
  }   
}
```

This is the function that checks all the other triggers to make sure that there isn't another one with the same name.

```
function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

[ScriptApp.newTrigger()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))

[ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getProjectTriggers())

While this is really handy for me.  I would still recommend that you go into the triggers panel and set the notifications to immediate so that you can get a quick email from Google while debugging your new code.  They will report errors immediately via email. It's extremely handy.

Animation:

[image]

Comment: I just added an installable trigger and everything is now working as intended! Thanks for all the help everyone!